# What determines whether Destiny enemies are vulnerable or resistant to a particular damage type?

Tags: destiny

[This page](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Damage_Type) lists the enemy shield types that are vulnerable to different damage types.  When I was playing recently, I noticed that a particular shielded enemy was resistant to Solar damage.  Are enemy shields that are vulnerable to one type of damage resistant to another type of damage?

Comment: related, but may not be a dupe: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184129/how-does-arc-solar-void-damage-work

Comment: Look at the color of the shields...it shows either what they are weak against or resistant too. Cannot remember what one it is so I will not answer.

Comment: In my experience, harder missions (such as the weekly heroic raid) have had enemies with shields that resist other types of damage (for instance, a blue shield was weak to Arc and strong against Solar).  

I have not noticed shield resists in regular raids (including lvl 24) and story missions up to lvl 24.  The damage didn't seem to be decreased either, same numbers popping up.

Comment: I won't answer because I'm not positive, but in harder strikes if you don't attack an enemy with the proper damage type for their shield you'll hardly damage them. I don't think it matters what type as long as you aren't using the one they are weak to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colored shields are weak to elements with the same color. If you shoot an enemy with a blue shield with a rocket launcher that causes void damage, you will still hurt him, but not do bonus elemental damage.

Bonus damage is usually displayed in the same color as the element, when shooting an anemy with the same colored shield.

Comment: Nothing in the game has a white shield.

Comment: I got mistaken with the blue shield Rapitor.  They looked same to me and i just assumed it took no other damage.  Thanks for the correction

Comment: No worries! In the heat of battle and in certain lighting the blue shield can look white.